# Does it matter what level of Prison of Elders I use my treasure key?

Tags: destiny

A treasure key can be used on any level of Prison of Elders after finishing it.  28, 32, 34, 35.  I know that completing higher levels gives additional completion rewards, cores, etheric light, etc.
Does it matter if I use a key on 28 vs. 35 for the chances to get better equipment?  I'm looking for something like the VoG and CE loot tables that explained which legendary and exotics dropped where.  Or, ideally, that it doesn't matter so I can turn them in on 28.

Comment: I'd like to know exactly this as well.

Comment: Also, [this page](http://destinytracker.com/destiny/wolvesloot) doesn't answer the question, but does show some things that you can get

Answer (score 5):

I don't know this for a fact, but to the best of my knowledge it doesn't matter, with one exception.

The loot table of the big chest is the same regardless of difficulty. The items you can get include Queen's weapons, and Fallen weapons (like what Variks sells in the Reef). The only exceptions to this are the following:

- The first time you open the big chest with a character, you will get an exotic item
- After Prison of Elders level 35, it can drop (this might be guaranteed, I'm not sure) a ship, shader, and/or emblem

I am saving 1 key for when I finish Prison of Elders on level 35. In addition, there is a chance that the [Elder Cipher](http://destiny.wikia.com/wiki/The_Elder_Cipher) will drop when defeating the final boss on Prison of Elders level 34 or 35. One of the steps of this bounty requires the Queen's Cipher, which only drops from the big chest in the challenge modes (level 32, 34, and 35), so it is a good idea to keep a few keys around for that as well.

Comment: Also good to note, the Queen's Cipher - which you need for the Elder Cipher bounties - only drops from the treasure chest in challenge modes, so 32, 34, and 35.

Comment: @VanBuzzKill thanks for that info - I've added it to my answer.

Comment: I have downed Skolas 8 times now. I have opened the large chest each time. I have gotten two ships, one emblem, and one shader from all of those rolls. I do not believe that it drops all three at the same time though (as *and* seems to indicate). Perhaps it can be edited to say "or"?

Comment: @TravisJ I edited it to say "and/or". The first time I did PoE 35, all 3 dropped. Since then it has either given me none of them, or some combination of them.

Answer (score 1):

From what I have read and seen from experience, the big chest is the same in all PoE instances. The differences are in the smaller chests, as guaranteed items will drop even if you don't have a key in levels 32, 34 and 35.

Also, the first time you open the big chest, the exotic is not guaranteed but the chance of getting one is increased. I know for a fact since I did witness a friend not getting an exotic on his first opening.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter if you use the key on the 28 compared to Skolas (35). The only difference that will occur is that chance of exotics. The lvl 28 prison has a lower chance for exotics where the 35 has a higher chances for exotics.

I hope this helped. Good luck Guardian.